Confusion about index manipulation in second variational formula for area
I've just picked up Peter Li's Geometric Analysis and am a bit confused about one equality in the derivation of the second variational formula for area. The setting is that we have some $n$-dimensional submanifold $N$ of an $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ with $n<m$ and a two-parameter family $\varphi:N\times(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\times(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\rightarrow M$ of deformations of $N$. As part of the derivation, we wish to compute the directional derivative $Sg^{ij}$ where $S=d\varphi(\frac{\partial}{\partial s})$, and Li asserts that
$$Sg^{ij}=-g^{il}(Sg_{lk})g^{kj}=-Sg_{ij}$$
The first equality is crystal clear to me, but I don't see why the second expression equals the third. For the same reasons as the first equality, we could write
$$Sg_{ij}=-g_{il}(Sg^{lk})g_{kj}$$
but then it's not clear to me why we would have $-g^{il}(Sg_{lk})g^{kj}=g_{il}(Sg^{lk})g_{kj}$. I thought it might be true for a particular choice of nice coordinates, but at this point we're supposed to be working in a "general coordinate system," so I guess it must be some obvious linear algebra that's eluding me for some reason.

What is $g^{ij}$?

@julio_es_sui_glace the matrix inverse of the metric in coordinates.

In coordinates, it’s matrix multiplication: $gg^{-1}g=g$

It only makes sense if $-\sum_{k,l=1}^n g^{ik}(Sg_{kl})g^{lj}=-\sum_{k,l=1}^n \delta^{ik}(Sg_{kl})\delta^{lj}=-Sg_{ij}$.

@TedBlack I guess he must be assuming normal coordinates again, then. Thank you!
